# having a real hard time with ST-Link

Tags: embedded, arm, stm32, keil, stm32f4discovery

I have a M24SR-Discovery board, STM32f103RG MCU, and I'm using Keil as IDE for programming. The thing is as much as I would like to get something done, I haven't even managed to communicate with it yet. Mainly I'm stuck when it comes to ST-Link.

In Keil the debugger says **No ST-LINK detected** and STM32 ST-LINK Utility says pretty much the same thing when I'm trying to connect to the device. Same story with ST-LinkUpgrade, and I'm starting to believe nobody really wants him, I guess :-)

I've tried the ST-LINK/V2 driver from here http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM146/CL1984/SC724/SS1677/PF251168 and the drivers "shipped" with Keil uVision4, that I've also found searching here and there under the term STLinkNucleoDriverSigned. I'm pretty much out of ideas and any other suggestion would be nice.

I have a 64 bit Windows 7 OS.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, unlike the other Discover series boards, after looking at the overview and schematics I don't believe the M24SR-Discovery contains an on-board ST-LINK adapter.

Most of the other Discovery boards have a small pinout STM32F103 dedicated to functioning only as the ST-LINK, and then a distinct processor setup as an application development target.  Your board seems to have only a larger pinout STM32F103 intended as an application target (wired up to LCD, peripherals, etc)

It does look like the USB pins are connected, but unlike on later chips the STM32F103's "ROM" bootloader does not support USB, so you could only load a program to it via USB if some flash-level secondary bootloader implementing that were on there.

Likely you should spend some time reading through the documentation and support info for the board.  Although the connector on its seems to break out full JTAG, it seems worth checking if the SWD subset (SWDCLK, SWDIO, POWER, GROUND) would work - if it would, then you can use any of the $10 or so STM32 discovery boards as your ST-LINK to program it just by pulling the jumpers off the other board and making up a **short** custom cable.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I definitely have too take a peak through its documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Me too, I have M24SR DIscovery.   Using Olimex ARM-USB-TINY-H ARM Jtag Debugger and OpenOCD I can configure it to talk to each other, and subsequently port 4444 is opened up.

```
sudo openocd -f ./olimex-arm-usb-tiny-h.cfg -f /usr/local/share/openocd/scripts/target/stm32f4x.cfg -d3
```

where olimex-arm-usb-tiny-h.cfg is as follows:

```
interface ftdi
ftdi_device_desc "Olimex OpenOCD JTAG ARM-USB-TINY-H"
ftdi_vid_pid 0x15ba 0x002a

ftdi_layout_init 0x0808 0x0a1b
ftdi_layout_signal nSRST -oe 0x0200
ftdi_layout_signal nTRST -data 0x0100 -oe 0x0100
ftdi_layout_signal LED -data 0x0800

adapter_khz 100
adapter_nsrst_delay 100
jtag_ntrst_delay 100
```

And my colleague using JLINK and OpenOCD it can get connected automatically, and stepping through instructions etc are all possible done through port 4444 windows.

Reference:   details are here:

http://tthtlc.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/how-to-do-jtag-debugging-using-openocd-and-olimex-arm-usb-tiny-h-on-m24sr-discovery/